# How to add Button id in XML in Android Studio 1.5？

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I spend a lot of time to search how resolve my problem but still unsuccessful, 
so I hope some one could help me.
Here is my code :

```
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_below="@id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/login"
            />
```

[image]

any other view is ok ,just Button

Comment: your id to button is right

Comment: This may or may not help, but every widget declared in XML *must* have the `android:layout_height` attribute declared. That said, please post your entire layout.

Comment: @AutonomousApps I add 'android:layout_height' in my code ,but still not ok.

Comment: Your id syntax is right.

Comment: Glad to help you..HappyCoding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you

right solution, namely by un-inject Language / Reference from suggestion. After that I was confused how to do it, finally I found out that using the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + A (on Windows) then typing “Un-inject Language / Reference”.